# Adding custom colors to Foundation Palette causes error (foundation-sites 6.3.1)

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I get this error message, when compiling the SCSS:

```
node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_color.scss
Error: given $key is not available in $foundation-palette
```

Here is the settings.scss file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by updating my settings.scss file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zurb/foundation-sites/develop/scss/settings/_settings.scss